# Total automatico con jquery en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Primeramente quiero decir que no soy experto en javascript, lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de ingresar otra cantidad o precio estas se multipliquen y me de la suma de ese item automaticamente en el input total, y a medida que yo vaya agregando un plan en la tabla, no se como hacerlo he estado buscado mucho información por internet y necesito ayuda.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //Funcion para agregar plan a la tabla
   function plan(plan_id) {
      $.ajax({
         url: '../buscar_plan.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {plan_id},
         success: function (e) {
            let planes = JSON.parse(e);
            let template = '';
            let cantidad = 1;
            let total = 0.00;
            planes.forEach(plan =>{
              total = plan.valor * cantidad;
               template += `
                  <tr id=${plan.id}>
                     <td class="id">${plan.id}</td>
                     <td>${plan.nombre}</td>
                     <td valor=${plan.valor}>
                        <input class="valor" type=number value="${plan.valor}" min="0">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input class="cantidad" type=number value="1" min="1">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input class="total" type=number value="${total}" readonly>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               `
            });
            $('#tablaplan').append(template);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

De aqui hago una consulta php para los planes y un boton que agrega el plan

```
<fieldset>
           <legend>Planes</legend>
            
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM plan; ";
                $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
            ?>
            <label for="plan">Planes:</label>
                <select name="plan" id="plan">
                    <?php
                        foreach ($resultado as $pl):
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $pl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $pl['nombre']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <div class="margin-bottom alinear-derecha">
                    <a id="addplan" class="boton boton-azul">Agregar</a>
                </div>

            <table id="tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Plan</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tablaplan">
                </tbody>
            </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hola Dario, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] así podes enterarte como funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que estas usando jQuery, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Te suscribis al evento `input` que suceda en los `input` de la tabla.
- Luego buscas los `input` de la fila donde se disparo el evento.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$('#tablaplan').on('input', 'input', function() {
  let $tr = $(this).closest('tr'), // buscamos la fila
    $valor = $tr.find('input.valor'),
    $cantidad = $tr.find('input.cantidad'),
    $total = $tr.find('input.total');
 
  // Calculamos y actualizamos el total
  $total.val(parseFloat($valor.val()) * parseFloat($cantidad.val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Plan</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tablaplan">
    <tr id=1>
      <td class="id">1</td>
      <td>nombre 1</td>
      <td valor=1>
        <input class="valor" type=number value="1" min="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="cantidad" type=number value="1" min="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="total" type=number value="1" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=2>
      <td class="id">2</td>
      <td>nombre 2</td>
      <td valor=2>
        <input class="valor" type=number value="2" min="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="cantidad" type=number value="1" min="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="total" type=number value="2" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Referencias:

- [jQuery.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [jQuery.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [jQuery.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [Evento `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo,  estaba sufriendo por eso.